# Source Not Available while trying to debug simple code

Tags: c++, visual-c++

While debugging, if (and only if) i have a break point in my node destructor i get this screen saying:

> > **Source Not Available**
> >
> > Source information is missing from the debug information for this module.
> >     You can view disassembly in the Disassembly window. To always view disassembly for missing source files, change the setting in the Options dialog.

([Here is a picture of the whole screen](http://screencast.com/t/Mayu38HGs))

I've looked everywhere on the net and the only "solution" i've found is moving the breakpoint which is not a real solution,
What can i do to fix the issue? Thanks.

(Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013)

Here is the code of the destructor which is one step before the screen appears:

```
MatchmakingAgency::Node::~Node(){
    cout << "Deleting: ";
    getClient()->printName();
    cout << endl;
    if (next){
        delete next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a guess, but the compiler might have optimized it.. are you debugging with optimization = off?

Comment: @cageman yes, optimization is disabled.

Comment: Can you show us what the source looks like one frame up on the call stack? ( In `MatchmakingAgency::Node::~Node()` )

Comment: You're trying to step into the scalar helping destructor, try to step out with Shift+F11 to get into the destructor

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae checked and both enabled.

Comment: @MarcoA. Thanks, using Shift+F11 kind of works but still, i would like to understand why is this happening, and if possible get a more permanent solution..

Comment: @argamanza where are you putting the breakpoint? VS does some manipulation to the code in order to set up those helpers. I can't exclude that you're getting a glitch in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments you're stepping into the scalar helping destructor (a helper function set up by Visual Studio for the destructor). You can also see this from the call stack.

Stepping out with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> should bring you directly into the destructor's code.

Regarding why this is happening it could be that Visual Studio is breaking into the helper function (glitch?) or that you're entering that function by stepping into it before the actual destructor code gets executed.

If that bothers you you might also take a look at [breakpoint macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5557y8b4.aspx) and see if that helps (try stepping out of the scalar deleting destructor if putting a breakpoint on the first line of the destructor doesn't help)

Answer (score 0):

You can show the stack window (Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Visual Studio 2013) and then double-click on a stack frame that is in your code to see where in your code the break is happening.